# the name of this theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, change-of-variable

What theorem justifies $\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-(x-ib)^2}dx=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2}dx$?

Initially I thought it is integration by substitution, but Wikipedia says [the codomain of the chain should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), which I think is not the case here?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058114/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175975/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!